# CFHTTP Connection Failure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfhttp

Just to give you a brief intro on what am I trying to achieve.

I need to scrape a value for each month from a public website.
As an example, for a particular status in the month of May, 2014; the TOTAL value is 224,481 (at the bottom right part of the page). I need to capture this value and store in the database for each of the month.
The following URL will need to be run by changing the parameters for each month.
[VEEC Website with params](https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx?Status=PRP,PRV&CreatedFrom=01-May-2014&CreatedTo=31-May-2014)

[image: May Total]

To achieve this, I am trying to get the HTML using CFHTTP as follows and then using `JSOUP` will scrape the intended value from the returned HTML before storing into the database.

```
<cfset f_url = "https://www.veet.vic.gov.au/Public/PublicRegister/Search.aspx">
    <cfhttp method="GET" url="#f_url#">
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*">
            <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
            <cfhttpparam name="CreatedFrom" type="URL"  value="#StartDate#">
            <cfhttpparam name="CreatedTo" type="URL"  value="#EndDate#">
            <cfhttpparam name="Status" type="URL"  value="PRP,PRV">
    </cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#">
```

I'm getting the `connection failure` error when I try to run the code snippet.

Please advise if there is an alternate way of doing the same. 
This has to be implemented just to gather data on the development side and not meant for production use.

**Edit (Didn't want to Delete the question)**: I had to use the internet proxy to access the website in the CFHTTP tag to make it work. My bad for not checking it earlier. Hopefully, it might help someone in future. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Works for me.  What do your `StartDate` and `EndDate` variables look like?  Is the server you're running this able to connect to that URL?

Comment: The dates are declared in the normal `csfet` tags. Yes, although the url is accesible from the CF server; i'm thinking the issue is related to IIS. Any thoughts on the same and ways to debug this?

Comment: declared how?  As strings like `31-May-2014`, as dates using `CreateDate()`, ...?  This article may be relevant: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2013/7/22/coldfusion.iis8.cfhttp

Comment: Sorry, yeah as strings only. Thanks for the link Duncan, i will work on it tomorrow.

Comment: What makes you think it is an issue related to IIS?

Comment: We've encountered past issues where some mail servers blocked email based on the default CFMail mailer id "ColdFusion Application Server".  Have you tried change the user agent in case the server blocks requests from the default CFHTTP user agent?  (The default value is "Cold Fusion".)

In addition, I would recommend using Firefox or Chrome dev tools so that you can view the GET request as performed from your browser.

Comment: Another option would be to use jsoup to get the HTML instead of using ColdFusion.  More information on this can be found at: 
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url

Comment: @duncan The link you mentioned talked about SNI and IIS 8. The response header from the link mentions the website is hosted on IIS7 so haven't been able to figure out the issue based on that link.

Comment: @JamesMoberg Thanks, I tried adding the user agent as "Mozilla"; still having the same issue. Also, jsoup connect also gave me the connection failure issue. Not sure if I am using it correctly. I'm using the jsoup object inside <cfscript> tags.

Comment: Also, I have imported and installed the public certificate from https://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/ since the website I'm trying to hit uses Geotrust certificate. But still having the same issue. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the classic secure cert thing.

CF has limited trust of secure certs. If the SSL cert at the destination you are calling is not one the CF likes, you will get a connection failure message. What you have to do is import the SSL cert in to the Java Keystore that CF is using.

Here is an old version of how to do it:
http://mkruger.cfwebtools.com/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=8E44925A-B73D-E3AD-709D4E02FD6D4588

Comment: Thanks for the link, Mark. This is what I did based on the link. I impored the base-64 public certificate from the hosted website and added the certificate using keytool. Still having the same issue. Am I missing something?